# Making one project with dependencies stand-alone in Eclipse (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Java project in Eclipse which has dependencies to other projects in my workspace. I'd like to find out what those dependencies are and copy them to my project in question, so that it doesn't need those other projects any more.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can go to project properties window and examine the "Java Build Path" page or "Project References" page.

Also you can examine the `.project` and `.classpath` file for first-level dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You could start closing those other projects and see if you get errors in building your main application.

If you're interested in how to manage inter-project dependencies, the common tool for java application dependency management is [Apache's Maven.](http://maven.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Export those projects as library jars, and physically copy them to your main project's /lib folder.